# Computer won't boot, UEFI beeps

Tags: memory, motherboard, power-supply, uefi

It has been a couple days by now and I am still trying to find out what the problem of my PC is. I have made a short video of what is happening when I run my PC on and in this video you might notice I have not installed the RAM cards, however when I do so, result will remain the exact same:

[Video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FB03GqTFvFY)

As you can hear in the video, the beeps being created indicate that there's a RAM problem according the following URL:

[URL here](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm)

I tried to replace RAM card(s) with another kind of RAM card (in order to test the RAM cards) but this did not help, result stays same. I tried to swap between slots aswell, single card and two cards, without the desired result.

I read on the internet it can be multiple things causing this, such as faulty PSU, motherboard and/or even CPU. Thing is I do not own the required hardware to test everything. Might need to buy cheap components which should be compatible with this motherboard.

The specs of the pc are:

- Processor: Intel Core i5 4670K
- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-Z87X-D3H
- PSU: XFX 550W Pro
- Memory:
  Corsair Vengeance LP CML8GX3M2A1600C9

Is there anyone who has experience in these kind of issues and recognized what is going on and is willing to help me out? Can anyone please explain me what is going on and how I can fix this issue so that this computer will run fine again?

**added pic of the machine taken from video linked to earlier**

[image]

**Edit:** Replaced PSU with another PSU and did ***not*** show any other result. Still experiencing the same problem.

Would using [this analyzer](http://www.benl.ebay.be/itm/261561054901?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) tool make it more clear for me what is going wrong? Is it compatible with UEFI?

Comment: technically, these days, I suppose it'd be the UEFI beeping, as BIOS isn't used anymore.

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean, but this does not answer my question though. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I don't know what the situation is with chipsets these days or recently but anyhow, have you plugged in the PSU into every required place. Last time I built a comp, and when I Have over the last 15 years, the few times I have, the PSU had to be plugged in not just in the 20ish pin plug.

Comment: You are probably refering to CPU connector, which should be connected and which is connected, In that case it's not only the 20 pin connector to be connected. Any other connector should not matter. I have to say it did work once when I was swapping spots with one of my memmories but I cannot reproduce that situation anymore somehow...

Comment: Is this all brand new or a build that was working and has stopped @Barrosy

Comment: [Those beeps are short not long which indicate a PSU problem not memory.](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/faq-page.aspx?fid=816).

Comment: Build that was wrking and has stopped @Linef4ult. Thank you for your comment Ramhound I should try a different PSU I suppose in order to confirm whatever you said might be true or not.

Comment: You should check to ensure all the pins are in place in the 4 and 24 pin connectors, if one is loose/missing it'll be easy to spot.

Comment: @Linef4ult yeah as I suggested. I can't see the PSU plugged in anywhere besides the 20ish(24pin) connector. And normally there is another connector where the PSU would plug in.

Comment: @barlop Which connector are you referring to if I may ask?

Comment: If you mean the 8 pin connector, that one is connected like I stated earlier on.

Comment: And to add up to @Linef4ult 's comment about ensuring all pins are there, there's one missing out but I assume that's the -5v rail which has been removed from many 24 pin connectors these days.

Comment: @Barrosy I guess  you have all the power cables in then..There wouldn't be another required besides that 8 pin. I've added a pic

Comment: AT Ramhound.. I guess maybe psu, though I heard about 48 short beeps.. then a gap then 48 short beeps, and so on, so how does that link you gave address that number of beeps and how does it indicate psu?

Comment: @barlop Probably a reference to the part in the link where it says: "Continuous short beep ：Power supply unit failed" where the 48 beeps are considered continuous, I suppose. Finding another PSU to test this is kind of an objective though. I will see if I can work that out and add it to this question.

Comment: Replaced PSU and still same result. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

> I have to say it did work once when I was swapping spots with one of
>   my memmories but I cannot reproduce that situation anymore somehow...
>   – Barrosy Jan 20 at 16:03

The fact that it worked once makes me lean towards ram/ram slot issues.

I'd be looking for some cheap(read: expendable, since you don't know where exactly the problem is) known-working(know anyone throwing out/selling a computer?) 1/2GB sticks that you can stick in there and see what happens.

The idea is to find out if you just have bad ram or a slot that's cooking your ram.

Bad ram should be a relatively easy fix(buying "new"/ known-working ram).

Bad slot you could get around with 1 larger stick (size depends on the motherboard's limit) and avoiding the bad slot.

(Guessing you probably don't have warranty on the board anymore?)

Comment: Like I said, I already tried replacing RAM and can't reproduce it anymore now somehow.. :/

Comment: Which you might see if the ram slot was cooking your ram...

'The idea is to find out if you just have bad ram or a slot that's cooking your ram.'

Comment: Could you provide me with information how I can get to the point of understanding wether this is the case (or confirm)? About warranty, that's correct. I just have it for about longer than 2 years now.

Comment: That's why i was saying getting a couple expendable sticks - i'd probably just find the cheapest 1GB sticks i could find, preferably from something being thrown out, and try this(in this order, and one ram stick at a time):

<code>    slot1 - ram1
    slot2 - ram1
    slot2 - ram2
    slot1 - ram2
    if slot2 cooks ram1, the computer will have tried to boot on slot1-ram1 and you'll know
    if slot1 cooks ram1, slot2 wont work with ram1 either, but when you try the next one (slot2-ram2), it should boot
</code>

[edit: wow I suck at formatting]

Comment: Yeah okay so you're just telling me something I already tried to do. I understand this kind of thing might help some people out but it did not help me out in the end. You basically tell me to get a RAM bank and try every slot and stuff. I already did try that. Thanks anyways.